# tcpdump - shows VLAN tag, but filtering doesn't work?

Tags: vlan, tcpdump

I'm running tcpdump on a mirrored port and when I use a simple tcpdump command it shows the VLAN id:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -n -e

22:02:53.308715 78:31:c1:c6:c8:9e (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 114: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, redacted-MBP.home.redacted.net.netbios-ns > 192.168.10.255.netbios-ns: NBT UDP PACKET(137): REFRESH(8); REQUEST; BROADCAST
```

However, if I try to filter on the vlan 10 id then it doesn't show any packets:

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -n -e '(vlan 10)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested on Fedora 23, tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.7.4
libpcap version 1.7.4
 It works. What is your distro, tcpdump version?

Comment: Support for shortcuts in BPF syntax is spotty across versions; for example I have tcpdump 4.1 and libpcap 1.4.0, and the 'vlan' shortcut does not work. It isn't pretty, but this BPF will work for `vlan 10`: `ether[12:2] = 0x8100 and ether[15] = 10`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your tcpdump version is too old, this should work starting from tcpdump 4.9.2 / libcap 1.5.3.

```
 tcpdump -i em2  -n -e  '(vlan 2002)'
```

works with these versions on a RHEL 7 system (loads of stuff output ...)